# More than one Primary Key in ASP.NET MVC Identity ASPNetUsers Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How can I add in another primary(composite) key into the table ASPNetUsers when using ASP.NET MVC Identity?

Usually I would do something like this:

```
[Required]
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public string AccountNo { get; set; }
```

But how can I do this using Identity?

Here is the start of my code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string AccountNo{ get; set; }....
```

But when I do this then the Id in the ASPNetUsers table is no longer a primary key. Where/what do I need to do so that in this table I have both Id and AccountNo as primary keys?

Comment: From what I know of Identity, this is not possible. You can customize the column type to use an int or something instead of the default of a string, but you only have one column as a key. Frankly, there's no need for anything else, and composite keys are usually a sign of poor database design, anyways. About the only good use is on a M2M join table, but even then, it's often better to have a true identity column.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you write your own custom provider.  Maybe you can get away with creating a Unique Index on that column and catch the specific exception when creating new users so that you can notify the user that a row with that account number already exists.